# a proactive folder watcher in Linux

Tags: python, linux

folder watcher functions in a way that after a file comes into a folder it does something ( it reacts ). Is there a method , such that, before a file enters the folder, a check is made, if it's a successful check then only the file enters folder, otherwise it does not.

Comment: I'm not aware of any API offering this (and it seems you'd need to hook the actual FS functions in the kernel directly (in the ext3 struct), but could you make it work with FUSE? http://sourceforge.net/p/fuse/wiki/LanguageBindings/#python

Comment: What does "does not" mean? What happens to the file that someone was trying to create or move there? What does the program that tried to create or move the file see? If you just want to be able to programmatically return `EACCES` or similar, that might be pretty easy, but if you're trying to do something more magical, that might be a different story.

Comment: Bear in mind that "a file enters the folder" isn't a single, discrete event. Typically the creation of the file, writing data to the file, seeking and/or reading it back, and any changes to the default owner, group, and permissions are all separate actions. So any "intercept" code will at best only see one part of this process.

Comment: "does not" means under certain condition file does not enter that folder. Condition being if a file does not have a proper naming convention then wishfully it should not enter a folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no existing solution to my knowledge. But:

- There is the inotify API, but that only gives out notifications of what just happened, i.e. you don't have any means to influence the result.
- If that is an absolutely necessary requirement, intercepting operations on a filesystem level is the only universal choice, hacking either the kernel itself or using FUSE.
- If you only want to monitor operations of a single process, you could intercept some calls using LD_PRELOAD to intercept some function calls like fopen() and fwrite().